# Replacing ActionBar title by custom image not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I wanted to replace `ActionBar` title(just title not icons) by an image (for example  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S8YP.png) I want the icon to remain the same but replace the title with another image )
.So I created a custom layout with `ImageView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_img"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_protect_go_white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then on my Oncreate(), I wrote the code:-

```
 RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBarOverlay);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);
                Window.SetFeatureInt(WindowFeatures.ActionBarOverlay, Resource.Layout.CustomActionBar_Title);
```

Here is my theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
```

but nothing is working and there is no error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Replacing ActionBar title by custom image not working

You could try using [Toolbar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/) to implement this feature :

> The Toolbar is an action bar component that provides more flexibility than the default action bar.

1. Create a Custom Theme

Open the `Resources/values/styles.xml`, replace its contents with the following `XML` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#5A8622</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Open the `Resources/values-21/styles.xml`, replace its contents with the following `XML` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <!--
     Base application theme for API 21+. This theme replaces
     MyTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 21+ devices.
    -->
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

2. Define a Toolbar Layout

In the `Resources/layout` directory, create a new file called `toolbar.xml`. Replace its contents with the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

3. Include the Toolbar Layout

Edit the layout file `Resources/layout/MainView.axml` and replace its contents with the following `XML`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**4. Find and Activate the Toolbar**

if you want "the icon to remain", you could find the `NavigationIcon` `ic_action_menu` in this [site](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=rgb(0%2C%200%2C%200)), you can find in **Clipart** part.

```cs
var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar> (Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_menu); //the icon to remain

//"replace ActionBar title(just title not icons) by an image", I think this is what you want
toolbar.SetLogo(Resource.Drawable.Icon); 
SupportActionBar.Title = "";

//Toolbar will now take on default actionbar characteristics
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

For more information, you could read the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/) or this [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/Toolbar/).

Effect :

[image]

**Update:**

In the `Resources/menu` subdirectory, create a new **XML** file called `home.xml` and replace the contents with the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
     android:id="@+id/menu_logo"
     android:icon="@drawable/logo" //assume this is your image, it will adjust its size according to your toolbar's size
     local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     android:title="Logo" />
  <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_social_share"
      local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="Share" />
 <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      local:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="Settings" />
</menu>
```

Inflate the `Menus` in your `Activity`:

```
// The options menu in which you place your items.
// This is the menu for the Toolbar/ActionBar to use
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.home, menu);
    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
}
```

Comment: How would you reduce the size of the logo image to fit inside the ToolBar ? .Everything is working .But when i put an image  to the toolbar it is bigger and doesn't look so good.Is there any specific size for toolbar logo ?

Comment: @Annu, I've updated the answer, you may have a check.

Comment: Thanks, 

What does local:showAsAction="ifRoom" mean?

Comment: @Annu, please refer to [Menu Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html),  Only place this item in the app bar if there is room for it. If there is not room for all the items marked "ifRoom", the items with the lowest orderInCategory values are displayed as actions, and the remaining items are displayed in the overflow menu.